# К каким элементам языка Java нельзя прикрепить аннотации?

Tags: java

К каким элементам языка Java нельзя прикрепить аннотации?
Например, Java не позволяет размещать аннотации над импортом библиотек.

```
@annot
import java.util.*;
```

В каких ещё случаях не разрешено использовать аннотации?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html

Answer (score 2):

на служебные операторы/блоки типа if, for и пр, generics

также можете взглянуть сюда http://www.seostella.com/ru/article/2012/05/20/annotacii-v-java-target.html

Comment: У меня вызывает диссонанс вопрос и ваш ответ.

Comment: Теперь вы сделали ответ-ссылку, что тоже не гуд.

Comment: а как бы порекомендовали? Исправлю

Comment: Ну у ваш ответ, это не ответ на вопрос, который задаётся. Это основная проблема. И лучше написать какой-то развернутый ответ, а ссылку привести как дополнение, а не как основную часть.

Comment: Нет, я решительно не понимаю когда минусуют за ответы, это верный ответ, может неполный...